# Cookie based authentication - Client side

Tags: php, authentication, curl, cookies, authorization

i am using Curl with PHP to get information from a website. This website uses cookie based authentication.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

$websiteUrl = 'http://some/url';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$getNewCookieFile =  dirname(__FILE__) . '/getNewCookieFile.txt';

$curlHandler = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, $websiteUrl);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $getNewCookieFile);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$mieteraktenSite = curl_exec($curlHandler);

curl_close($curlHandler);


$getNewCookieFileText = file_get_contents('getNewCookieFile.txt');

$sessionName = 'JSESSIONID';
if ($sessionNameIndex = strpos($getNewCookieFileText, $sessionName)) {
    $sessionValue = substr($getNewCookieFileText, $sessionNameIndex + strlen($sessionName) + 1, 46);
    file_put_contents('cookie.txt', $sessionValue);
}


$auth = base64_encode("$username:$password");
$sessionId = file_get_contents('cookie.txt');

$headers = [
    'Cookie'   => "ELO-Approved=; JSESSIONID=$sessionId",
    'Authorization' => "Basic $auth"
];


$sessionId = file_get_contents('cookie.txt');

$cookieContext = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header'  => array_map(function ($h, $v) {
            return "$h: $v";
        }, array_keys($headers), $headers)
    ]
]);

$documentsLink = "$websiteUrl/authorization/required";
$documentsSite = file_get_contents($documentsLink, false, $cookieContext);

echo $documentsSite;
```

The problem is that the website sends invalid cookie. When I try to use this cookie to get authorized, it does not work. However if I visit this website from the browser everything works fine. And if copy the cookie saved in this browser and put it in the cookie.txt file, this works also.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: The site might not be using basic URL authentication. No way I can check this though.

Comment: This is hard to say. If the remote website wants to discourage this kind of activity, it could have placed some roadblocks.
So it could be many things, like referrer-check (where did the request come from).
Or maybe the remote site only want a cookie (and no username:password) after the session started.
If you really want to see what is send, better use Firefox and use ctrl-Shift-i to launch tools, and have a look at the networking tab

Comment: Automatic authentication with cookies is prone to CSRF attacks. Your website may have security against this